# .drawing extension file for Xcode project for PencilKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pencilkit

How can I make my own .drawing file to import it in Xcode to get drawing from this file and assign to PKDrawing and then draw it in PKCanvas view?
I've explored WWDC2020 PencilKit demo project where they are also using .drawing file of lowercased and uppercased letters to draw them on the Canvas View.
Thanks

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10148/

Answer (score 0):

What I did, load not .drawing file, but rather .data. So, I created button to save it in data.

```
@IBAction func share(_ sender: Any) {
        let data = canvasView.drawing.dataRepresentation()
        let drawingNum = String(drawingIndex + 1)
        let sFilename = drawingNum + ".data"
        let documentDirectorypath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let documentURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectorypath).appendingPathComponent(sFilename)
        do {
            try data.write(to: documentURL)
            let banner = FloatingNotificationBanner(title: "Saved", style: .success)
            banner.show()
            print("success")
        }
        catch {
            let banner = FloatingNotificationBanner(title: "Can not save", subtitle: "Are you sure that you give me permission?", style: .danger)
            banner.show()
        }
    }
```

Then I just load this .data file. This is the only way, I found. However, I do not understand how to create .drawing file.